# Number theory question on primes and divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For which primes $p$ is $2^p+1$ divisible by $p$?

I am not quite sure how to approach this.

Comment: start with  Fermat's little theorem

Comment: Would it work to just use how we have $2^p+1\equiv 0 mod p$ (since it is was it is given) and then Fermat's theorem gives us $2^p\equiv 2$ mod $p$. The first equation turns into $2^p \equiv -1$ mod $p$. Therefore, $p$ has to be 3.

Answer (score 3):

We can write the following equation to solve your question:

$$2^p + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
$$2^p \equiv -1 \pmod p$$

Obviously $p=2$ won't satisfy the congruence relation, because $2^2 \not\equiv -1 \pmod 2$. So it implies tha p is an odd number.

Because p is an odd number that means that $-1 = (-1)^p$

So we have:

$$2^p \equiv (-1)^p \pmod p$$

From congruence relation we know that

$$a^n \equiv b^n \pmod c \text{    if and only if     }    a \equiv b \pmod c$$

So we can simplify the relation to:

$$2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$$
$$3 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

From this follows that $3 = pk$, for $k \in \mathbb{R}$, but the only prime factor of 3 is 3, so it follows that $p=3$

Answer (score 2):

By [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) if $p\ne 2$ then $2^p+1=2(2^{p-1}-1)+3\equiv 3\mod p$. Hence $p=3$.

Comment: Based on the cited Wikipedia entry, it suffices to say $2^p+1\equiv2+1=3\mod p$.

Comment: @ Stefan4024 : Thank you. I don't know to use URL correctly. :-(

Comment: @  Barry Cipra : Of course. I tried to make more understandable for OP.

Comment: I just meant that the version stated in the Wikipedia entry is $a^p\equiv a\mod p$ for *all* $a$, so it's not necessary to use the $a^{p-1}-1$ version.

Comment: @ Barry Cipra : Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the problem with the FLT:

$$2^p=\binom{p}{0}+\binom{p}{1}+...+\binom{p}p=2+\left[\binom{p}{1}+\binom{p}{2}+...+\binom{p}{p-1} \right] $$

Now use the fact that each of the terms in $\binom{p}{1}+\binom{p}{2}+...+\binom{p}{p-1}$ is divisible by $p$.

**P.S.** This proof actually proves the FLT in the case $a=2$, so is not really independent of FLC.