# Primes Number Theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For which primes $p$ is $2^p+1$ divisible by $p$?

What I have been doing is:

$2^p+1\equiv 0\pmod p$

$2^p\equiv -1\pmod p$

Then by Fermat's Theorem, we get

$2^p\equiv 2\pmod p$

This shows $p=1,3$.

I feel like this is not right though...

Comment: Why do you feel this is not right? This is exactly the argument that you got from two answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499009/number-theory-question-on-primes-and-divisibility). Just note that $1$ isn't a prime.

Comment: Can you conclude from just $2^p\equiv-1(mod p)$ and $2^p\equiv 2(mod p)$  that p has to be 1 or 3? I felt like I jumped too far.

Comment: You *can* conclude that $2 \equiv -1 \mod{p}$, so that $p | 3$.

Comment: I guess the OP's problem is more in that they are *no other* solutions. True?

Answer (score 4):

You have the congruence $2^{p}-2\equiv 0\pmod p$. Thus $p|2^{p}-2$ and $p|2^{p}+1$. So $p$ divides their difference which is $3$.